# Pass image to gradient function for yolo3 from GlounCV model Zoo

Tags: python, yolo, mxnet, gluon, mxnet-gluon

I am trying to get the gradient with respect to a specific images (sitting in adv_loader). These images are loaded in adv_loader. I tried just taking the code that was calculating the gradient in the backprop step but Yolo3 doesn’t seem to have a grad attribute. Any ideas on how to get that?

```
import mxnet as mx
import gluoncv as gcv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mxnet import gluon
from gluoncv.loss import YOLOV3Loss
import time
ctx = [mx.gpu(i) for i in range(mx.context.num_gpus())] if mx.context.num_gpus()>0 else [mx.cpu()]
#Datasets
train = gcv.data.RecordFileDetection('./data/train.rec',coord_normalized=False)
val = gcv.data.RecordFileDetection('./data/val.rec',coord_normalized=False)
classes = ['Passenger Vehicle','Small Car','Bus']

net = gcv.model_zoo.yolo3_mobilenet0_25_custom(pretrained_base=False,classes=classes,ctx=ctx)
net.collect_params().initialize(force_reinit=True,ctx=ctx)

import multiprocessing as mp
### The following looks nasty, and I apologize for the difficulty but basically what we are doing is 
# transforming our data so it is in the correct format for yolo3
batch_size = 32 #This can be changed, but it determines how often we update our model.
num_workers = mp.cpu_count()//2
### We will import the following to reduce what i need to type (I am not sure about you but I like being lazy)
from mxnet import autograd

### 416 is our width/height we want the network to train on
sizes = 328

train_transform = gcv.data.transforms.presets.yolo.YOLO3DefaultTrainTransform(sizes,sizes, net)

# return stacked images, center_targets, scale_targets, gradient weights, objectness_targets, class_targets
# additionally, return padded ground truth bboxes, so there are 7 components returned by dataloader
batchify_fn = gcv.data.batchify.Tuple(*([gcv.data.batchify.Stack() for _ in range(6)] + [gcv.data.batchify.Pad(axis=0, pad_val=-1) for _ in range(1)]))
train_loader = mx.gluon.data.DataLoader(train.transform(train_transform), batch_size, shuffle=True,
                          batchify_fn=batchify_fn, last_batch='rollover',num_workers=num_workers,prefetch=num_workers + num_workers//2)

val_batchify_fn = gcv.data.batchify.Tuple(gcv.data.batchify.Stack(), gcv.data.batchify.Pad(pad_val=-1))
val_transform = gcv.data.transforms.presets.yolo.YOLO3DefaultValTransform(sizes,sizes)



val_loader = mx.gluon.data.DataLoader(
        val.transform(val_transform),
        batch_size, False, batchify_fn=val_batchify_fn, last_batch='keep',num_workers=num_workers,prefetch=num_workers + num_workers//2)

adv_loader = mx.gluon.data.DataLoader(train.transform(train_transform), batch_size, shuffle=True,
                          batchify_fn=batchify_fn, last_batch='rollover',num_workers=num_workers,prefetch=num_workers + num_workers//2) #this is a placeholder for data that will generate advarsaial examples


#How we will validate our model
def validate(net, val_data, ctx, eval_metric):
    """Test on validation dataset."""
    eval_metric.reset()
    # set nms threshold and topk constraint
    net.set_nms(nms_thresh=0.45, nms_topk=455)
    mx.nd.waitall()
    net.hybridize()
    for batch in val_data:
        data = mx.gluon.utils.split_and_load(batch[0], ctx_list=ctx, batch_axis=0, even_split=False)
        label = mx.gluon.utils.split_and_load(batch[1],  ctx_list=ctx,batch_axis=0, even_split=False)
        det_bboxes = []
        det_ids = []
        det_scores = []
        gt_bboxes = []
        gt_ids = []
        gt_difficults = []
        for x, y in zip(data, label):
            # get prediction results
            ids, scores, bboxes = net(x)
            det_ids.append(ids)
            det_scores.append(scores)
            # clip to image size
            det_bboxes.append(bboxes.clip(0, batch[0].shape[2]))
            # split ground truths
            gt_ids.append(y.slice_axis(axis=-1, begin=4, end=5))
            gt_bboxes.append(y.slice_axis(axis=-1, begin=0, end=4))
            gt_difficults.append(y.slice_axis(axis=-1, begin=5, end=6) if y.shape[-1] > 5 else None)

        # update metric
        eval_metric.update(det_bboxes, det_ids, det_scores, gt_bboxes, gt_ids, gt_difficults)
    return eval_metric.get()

eval_metric = gcv.utils.metrics.voc_detection.VOCMApMetric(class_names=classes)
nepochs=11

net.initialize(force_reinit=True)
net.collect_params().reset_ctx(ctx)

#Grab a trainer or optimizer to perform the optimization    
trainer = mx.gluon.Trainer(net.collect_params(),'adam',
                            {'learning_rate':0.001},
                            kvstore='device')


for i in range(nepochs):
    now = time.time()
    mx.nd.waitall()
    net.hybridize(static_alloc=True,static_shape=True)
    for ixl,batch in enumerate(train_loader):
        data = mx.gluon.utils.split_and_load(batch[0], ctx_list=ctx, batch_axis=0)
        # objectness, center_targets, scale_targets, weights, class_targets
        fixed_targets = [mx.gluon.utils.split_and_load(batch[it], ctx_list=ctx, batch_axis=0) for it in range(1, 6)]
        gt_boxes = mx.gluon.utils.split_and_load(batch[6], ctx_list=ctx, batch_axis=0)
        sum_losses = []
        with autograd.record():
            for ix, x in enumerate(data):
                obj_loss, center_loss, scale_loss, cls_loss = net(x, gt_boxes[ix], *[ft[ix] for ft in fixed_targets])
                sum_losses.append(obj_loss + center_loss + scale_loss + cls_loss)
            autograd.backward(sum_losses)
        trainer.step(batch_size)
    
for ixl,batch in enumerate(adv_loader):
    data = mx.gluon.utils.split_and_load(batch[0], ctx_list=ctx, batch_axis=0)
    # objectness, center_targets, scale_targets, weights, class_targets
    fixed_targets = [mx.gluon.utils.split_and_load(batch[it], ctx_list=ctx, batch_axis=0) for it in range(1, 6)]
    gt_boxes = mx.gluon.utils.split_and_load(batch[6], ctx_list=ctx, batch_axis=0)
    sum_losses = []
    with autograd.record():
        for ix, x in enumerate(data):
            obj_loss, center_loss, scale_loss, cls_loss = net(x, gt_boxes[ix], *[ft[ix] for ft in fixed_targets])
            sum_losses.append(obj_loss + center_loss + scale_loss + cls_loss)
        autograd.backward(sum_losses,retain_graph=True)
        print(net.grad.asnumpy())
```

I am getting told here that AttributeError: 'YOLOV3' object has no attribute 'grad'. I am using this documentation https://mxnet.apache.org/versions/1.6/api/python/docs/tutorials/packages/autograd/index.html
Any idea how to get an image and pass it through to the gradient of the yolo loss function?